# Why Viber giving a errors about JS?

Tags: ubuntu, debian-based, viber

I tried to install Viber on Ubuntu via AppImage, and got this logs:

```
└─$ ./viber.AppImage                            
../run.sh: line 17: [: so many arguments
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
qt.webenginecontext: 

GLImplementation: desktop
Surface Type: OpenGL
Surface Profile: NoProfile
Surface Version: 2.0
Using Default SG Backend: yes
Using Software Dynamic GL: no
Using Angle: no

Init Parameters:
  *  allow-loopback-in-peer-connection  
  *  application-name ViberPC 
  *  autoplay-policy no-user-gesture-required 
  *  browser-subprocess-path /tmp/.mount_viber.CE8wet/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess 
  *  disable-features DnsOverHttpsUpgrade,ConsolidatedMovementXY,InstalledApp,BackgroundFetch,WebOTP,WebPayments,WebUSB,PictureInPicture,AudioServiceOutOfProcess 
  *  disable-setuid-sandbox  
  *  disable-speech-api  
  *  enable-features NetworkServiceInProcess,TracingServiceInProcess,NetworkServiceInProcess 
  *  enable-threaded-compositing  
  *  enable-usermedia-screen-capture  
  *  in-process-gpu  
  *  use-gl desktop 

Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
QHighDpiScaling::setFactor: Should only be called when no windows exist.
qml: CALL_WEB_VIEW_DEBUG: callWebEngineLoader active: false
qml: Current screen: eDP-1 [w=1920, h=1080, daw=1920, dah=1036, dpr=1]
qml: Geometry: mh=0, mw=0, h=0, w=0, sah=1036, saw=1920
qml: Position: x=960, y=986
qml: Geometry: mh=0, mw=959, h=0, w=959, sah=1036, saw=1920
qml: Position: x=481, y=986
qml: Geometry: mh=112, mw=959, h=112, w=959, sah=1036, saw=1920
qml: Position: x=481, y=874
qml: videoPreviewWindow active: false
qml: incomingCallWindow active: false
qml: notificationsWindow active: false
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
[15615:15615:0125/110906.712032:ERROR:create_gr_gl_interface.cc(287)] Failed to initialize extensions
[15615:15615:0125/110906.714348:ERROR:create_gr_gl_interface.cc(287)] Failed to initialize extensions
qt.qml.context: qrc:/Resources/QML/Feed/FeedView.qml:266:13 Parameter "bottom" is not declared. Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead.
../run.sh: строка 80: 15615 Ошибка сегментирования                   (образ памяти сброшен на диск) ../Viber
```

Tried anything... not works for me.. What I need to do?

I tried to re-install Viber = same result
Tried to install OpenGL = same result
Tried to install more old libraries (that dont have compatibility probs) = same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install QT 6 and developer extensions / packages, also the latest appimage works *only* on debian SID